# No matching distribution found for matplotlib.finance

Tags: python

!pip install matplotlib.finance

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement matplotlib.finance (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for matplotlib.finance

from matplotlib.finance import candlestick_ohlc
from matplotlib.dates import DateFormatter, date2num, WeekdayLocator, DayLocator, MONDAY

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'matplotlib.finance'

anyone help me solve this problem~ Thanks

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

That looks to be an old package that is no longer available. It seems [mplfinance](https://pypi.org/project/mplfinance/) is the way to go now.

```
pip install mplfinance
```